# Doctrine embeddable

Tags: php, doctrine, domain-driven-design, value-objects, embeddable

I am trying to implement doctrine2 **embeddable** feature for value objects.

This is simple snippet, slightly modified [from doctrine official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html):

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    protected $address;
   /** @Column(type = "string") */
    protected $street;
}

/** @Embeddable */
class Address
{
    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    protected $street;

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    protected $postalCode;

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    protected $city;

    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    protected $country;
}
```

When I try to access property from embedded object, I am getting "*cannot access protected property*" error - which is expected.
Embeddable objects should be read only by their base entity class, and not modified since they are immutable (following domain driven design guidelines).
What  I don't understand is how can I read their properties since they are private/protected ? Is there any PHP magic involved here ? I was trying to use different getters like:

```
getStreet(Address $address){
    $this->street = $address->street;
}
```

but always get error, before calling persist and flush methods on entity manager instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would make a column/property called street in your user class?  Address of course already has one.

Comment: Legit question, but you cannot assume it's the same "street" concept, without knowing the domain he/she's trying to model. Anyway, I agree that is confusing and it should deserve a better name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the street value starting from a user, you should create a getter method in the User class that internally has access to the address and does:

```
class User
{
    public getAddressStreet() {
        $this->address->getStreet();
    }
}
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getters` on the embedded class.

```
class Address
{
    ...
    public function getStreet(){
        return $this->street;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, your method changes

```
getStreet(Address $address){
    $this->street = $address->getStreet();
}
```